# How can I upload images in backend in Next.js API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am using Next.js with API. I want to upload two files and add one input text field by using API backend. I tried but i couldn't find a solution for upload files with different fields and one input text field in the backend. How can i save images which i uploaded from my desktop or personal computer(not an image link)

```
const Information = () => {
    const [institute_logo, setInstitute_logo] = useState('');
    const [institute_about_head, setInstitute_about_head] = useState('');
    const [institute_about_upload, setInstitute_about_upload] = useState('');
                                              
    const Info = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.patch(`/api/institute/Information/${Id}`, {
            institute_logo,
            institute_about_head,
            institute_about_upload   
        }            
    }
                    
    return (   
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={Info}>
                <input 
                    type="file"
                    id="institute_logo"
                    name="institute_logo"
                    placeholder="Upload Image" 
                    className='shadow appearance-none border-gray rounded w-1/2 py-2 px-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline'
                    onChange={logo}
                />
                <div className='mt-2 flex flex-col'>
                    <label htmlFor="institute_about_head" className='font-medium'>Main Heading</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        id="institute_about_head"
                        name="institute_about_head"
                        placeholder="About Us" 
                        className='border-2 border-gray-light rounded w-3/4 pl-1.5 h-9 mt-1'
                        onChange={(e) => setInstitute_about_head(e.target.value)} 
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input 
                        type="file"
                        id="institute_about_upload" 
                        name="institute_about_upload"
                        placeholder="Upload Image" 
                        className='border-2 border-gray-light rounded w-3/4 pl-1.5 h-9 mt-2 shadow appearance-none' 
                        onChange={(e) => setInstitute_about_upload(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
                
export default Information;
```

API backend

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    let {Id} = req.query;
    if (req.method === 'PATCH') {
        let {
            institute_logo, 
            institute_about_upload, 
        } = req.files
                    
        let {
            institute_about_head
        }  = req.body;
                        
        const payload = {
            institute_about_head
        }
                            
        let instituteAdditionalData = await institute.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: instituteId }, payload, { new: true }).lean();
        if (instituteAdditionalData) {
            res.status(200).json({Message:"Institute Details updated successfully"})
        }
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need the answer, but I ran into a similar problem and found the answer here

https://codesandbox.io/s/thyb0?file=/pages/index.js

NOTE: Make sure to install the packages with their exact version number. Formidable must be version 1.2.2 for it to work.
(npm install formidable@1.2.2)

If you use the latest version, it won't work as shown in the code.

It solves the problem of image uploads, but definitely try to check out how it would work in the latest version.

Hope this helps!